# Unable to run Turtle graphics script more than one time in PythonWin

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, pywin32

Learning Python and coded simple Turtle graphics script using PythonWin. The script will execute only one time from PythonWin. On subsequent attempt, the script hangs on the line that creates the turtle class instance, x=turtle.Turtle(). I need to restart PythonWin to run the script.
However, same script can be executed more than once from IDLE.

Using Python 3.7.2 (64-bit) and PythonWin 3.7 (64-bit)

Here's the code

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
tess = turtle.Turtle() --->hangs here
dist = 5
tess.up()                     # this is new
for pas in range(30):    # start with size = 5 and grow by 2
    tess.stamp()                # leave an impression on the canvas
    tess.forward(dist)          # move tess along
    tess.right(24)              # and turn her
    dist = dist + 2
wn.exitonclick()
```

Ran the script in debugger and got these errors

```
>>> Unhandled exception while debugging...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions: remove this line altogether:

```
wn.exitonclick()
```

or, if that doesn't make things any better, replace it with:

```
wn.mainloop()
```

Generally, within a running Python image, turtle is *not* reentrant.  It fails with `Terminator` upon restart.  Once turtle quits, it's done.  But some interactive environments know this, so they handle a `mainloop()` call specially.  Or not.  Your environment may not be setup to handle `exitonclick` which is a `mainloop()` call combined with an event handler that calls `turtle.bye()`.

Answer (score 0):

The module uses a class variable _RUNNING which remains true between executions when running in spyder instead of running it as a self contained script. I have requested for the module to be updated.

Meanwhile, work around/working example

1)

```
import importlib
import turtle
importlib.reload(turtle)
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
tess = turtle.Turtle()
dist = 5
tess.up()                     # this is new
for pas in range(30):    # start with size = 5 and grow by 2
    tess.stamp()                # leave an impression on the canvas
    tess.forward(dist)          # move tess along
    tess.right(24)              # and turn her
    dist = dist + 2

wn.exitonclick()
```

2. 

```
import importlib
import turtle
importlib.reload(turtle)
wn = turtle.Screen()
turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING=True
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")
tess = turtle.Turtle()
dist = 5
tess.up()                     # this is new
for pas in range(30):    # start with size = 5 and grow by 2
    tess.stamp()                # leave an impression on the canvas
    tess.forward(dist)          # move tess along
    tess.right(24)              # and turn her
    dist = dist + 2

wn.exitonclick()
```